# What controls beta entitlement on App Store distribution profile?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store, provisioning-profile

I've created a Xamarin Forms app. This Microsoft link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/testflight?tabs=macos#provisioning
) states that to put the app in TestFlight I need to create a new App Store distribution profile which will have the beta entitlement, which I have done. My app is in TestFlight now.

What are next steps as far as the provisioning profile? Do I need to create a new provisioning profile for submitting it to App Store, or do I need to do something to the one that I have already created to turn off the beta entitlement? Is all of that handled automatically? Thanks

Comment: It's not necessary. I think it depends on what you want to do. And in App Store Connect, when you submit an ipa build in TestFlight, you could also select and use that build when adding for review.

Comment: What's not necessary? If I select and use a build that's currently in TestFlight when I'm ready to publish to the App Store like you said, is there anything I would need to do with the provisioning profile?

Comment: Actually, I think you don't have to change the provisioning profile. But it depends on the Apple staff‘s decision. If they approve your submission, then it's fine. If they think you need to change, then do as they say. You could also communicate with them about your concerns during the review.